# Roku app "ObserveField visible" is not running when the screen appears

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on an app for Roku using BrightScript and SceneGraph. I have a postergrid where a user selects between a number of posters. When the user selects one, the ShowTopicScreen sub is called:

ShowTopicScreen.brs

```vb
sub ShowTopicScreen(topic as Object)
    topicScreen = CreateObject("roSGNode", "TopicScreen")
    topicScreen.content = topic
    topicScreen.ObserveField("visible", "OnDetailsScreenVisibilityChanged")
    ShowScreen(topicScreen)
    end sub

    sub OnTopicScreenVisibilityChanged(event as Object)
    visible = event.GetData()
    currentScreen = GetCurrentScreen()
    screenType = currentScreen.SubType()
    if visible = false
        if screenType = "HomeScreen"
            currentScreen.jumpToItem = m.selectedTopicIndex
        end if
    end if
end sub
```

The Topic Screen is supposed to read the content data and populate a label and load certain data to a rowlist (which is still under development)

TopicScreen.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <component name="TopicScreen" extends="Group" initialFocus="topicList">
    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="TopicScreen.brs" />
    
    <interface>
        <!-- Specifies the content for the Grid -->
        <field id="content" type="assocarray" />
        <field id="topiccontent" type="node" alias="topicList.content" />
        <field id="rowItemSelected" type="intarray" alwaysnotify="true" alias="topicList.rowItemSelected" />
        <field id="jumpToRowItem" type="intarray" alias="topicList.jumpToRowItem" />
    </interface>
    <children>
        <Label
            id="titleLabel"
            width="1020"
            translation="[105,170]"
        />

        <Label
            id="textLabel"
            width="1020"
            translation="[105,190]"
            text="A test label"
        />
         
        <RowList
            itemComponentName="TopicRowListItemComponent"
            id="topicList"
            translation="[105,240]"
            numRows="2"
            rowitemSize="[[320,180]]"
            rowItemSpacing="[[20,0]]"
            itemSize="[1100,270]"
            rowLabelOffset="[[50,20]]"
            focusXOffset="[50]"
            showRowLabel="[true]"
            rowFocusAnimationStyle="floatingfocus"
        />
    </children>
    </component>
```

TopicScreen.brs

```vb
sub Init()
    m.top.observeField("visible", "onVisibleChange")

    m.titleLabel = m.top.FindNode("titleLabel")
    end sub

    sub onVisibleChange()
    'this only runs when I leave the screen
    if m.top.visible = true
        SetContent()
    end if
    end sub

    sub SetContent() 
    m.titleLabel = m.top.topic.title
end sub
```

The problem is that the OnVisibleChange sub is never called (it is called when I press the back button to go to the first screen, however, if I go back to the topics screen, again it's not called). The TopicScreen is loading as I can see the static label ("A test label") on screen.

Why if the OnVisibleChange() sub not being called and how can I get the data to populate the label?

Answer (score 1):

Your observer will only be fired if the `visible` field changes from one value to the other, unless you have defined `notifyAlways` as true for that field, but regardless, the observer callback fires off after the `visible` value is assigned. I don't see anywhere in your code how are you assigning the `visible` value.

Maybe you want to observe `renderTracking` instead? See more details in the [Group class reference](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/layout-group-nodes/group.md).

```
sub init()
  (...)

  m.top.enableRenderTracking = true
  m.top.observeField("renderTracking", "onVisibilityChange")
end sub

sub onVisibilityChange()
  if m.top.renderTracking = "full" ' Based on your needs you might want to check for "partial" as well.
      (...)
  end if
end sub
```